# Collaborating on a journal paper and a possibility of conflict of interest

Tags: publications, conflict-of-interest

I graduated with a PhD and now work in a CAE related industry. My former PhD colleague who is enrolled in some university as a postdoc reached out to me for a collaboration on a journal paper. Although I am yet to respond to her with questions pertaining my role in it, I see a serious conflict of interest on my part because I work on a similar thing at my industry job. Does my appreciation carry any weight? Do I need to talk to my boss before I indulge myself into this? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you need to talk to your boss.

Comment: In fact often you will need formal permission from your employer to publish.

Comment: Conflicts of interest need to be declared, they don't prohibit you from working on a topic, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

One would expect that industry people working in computer aided engineering would work on, and publish on, computer aided engineering. The conflict comes not in the work or publication per se, but in the possibility that you/your company are using the publication to sell your product by making it look better than it perhaps is (yes, that is not the full story).

It is not a conflict of interest for IBM to publish papers on semiconductor processing, even though they produce semiconductors (although the general feeling in the community was that if IBM published it they had decided it wasn't good enough). It is not a conflict for Bell Labs to publish papers on telephone networks, or fiber optics. Google publishes on any number of things related to searching and big data.

That said, as @Kimball noted, you will want formal permission from the company, usually including a formal review and approval process, for you to publish. And you may have to fill in the conflict of interest form, but that relates more to the exact publication. If the subject is some theory of how to do something faster, perhaps not. If it is a comparison of your company's product with others, you bet.